# SQL left join on multiple columns return partial matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

We currently do validation on our data using a LEFT JOIN from a lookup table, these are on single tables to single columns, just a normal left join to one table then we do a case statement in the SELECT to say if returned value is greater than zero (not null) then it's ok, else warning. Process currently looks like the below:

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN LEN(C_Market.MCode) > 0 THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning' END AS C_Market
CASE WHEN LEN(C_Language.LCode) > 0 THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning' END AS C_Language

FROM [dbo].[CTable]

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Lookup_Market] AS C_Market ON [dbo].CTable.[campaignNameMarket] = C_Market.MCode
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Lookup_Language] AS C_Language ON [dbo].CTable.[campaignNameLanguage] = C_Language.LCode
```

What we are looking to do is validate across multiple columns so adding an AND to our LEFT JOIN statements. This will be based off mapped lookup tables. Our issue is that if one of the columns don't match, it returns all columns in LEFT JOIN/AND as NULL (which makes sense). Would there be a way of doing the multiple join but still return the value if it matches that column in the LEFT JOIN/AND statement but only return NULL on the column that does not match? Any help would be much appreciated

Example:

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN LEN(C_MarketLanguage.LCode) > 0 THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning' END AS C_Language,
CASE WHEN LEN(C_MarketLanguage.MCode) > 0 THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning' END AS C_Market

FROM [dbo].[CTable]

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LookupMap_MarketLanguage] AS C_MarketLanguage ON [dbo].CTable.[campaignNameMarket] = C_MarketLanguage.MCode
AND [dbo].CTable.campaignNameLanguage = C_MarketLanguage.LCode
```

See below example of the LookupMap_MarketLanguage table. Here we will do a left join on MCode AND LCode. Lets say for example the main table had CH as the Market but CZE as the Language. The old method with individual left joins would say they are both ok as they are in each column however the new AND method would show both as warning. I would like Market to show as OK but Language to show as warning.

```
LookupMap_MarketLanguage Table
+----------------+-------+----------+-------+
|     Market     | MCode | Language | LCode |
+----------------+-------+----------+-------+
| Switzerland    | CH    | French   | FRE   |
| Switzerland    | CH    | German   | GER   |
| Czech Republic | CZ    | Czech    | CZE   |
| Germany        | DE    | German   | GER   |
+----------------+-------+----------+-------+
```

```
Sample CTable data
+--------------------+----------------------+
| campaignNameMarket | campaignNameLanguage |
+-------------------------------------------+
| DE                 | GER                  |
| CH                 | CZE                  |
| CZ                 | CZE                  |
+--------------------+----------------------+
```

```
Desired output
+----------+-------------+
| C_Market | C_Language  |
+----------+-------------+
| Ok       | Ok          |
| Ok       | Warning     |
| Ok       | Ok          |
+----------+-------------+
```

```
Current output with multiple left joins
+----------+-------------+
| C_Market | C_Language  |
+----------+-------------+
| Ok       | Ok          |
| Ok       | Ok          |
| Ok       | Ok          |
+----------+-------------+
```

```
Current output with AND LEFT JOIN
+----------+-------------+
| C_Market | C_Language  |
+----------+-------------+
| Ok       | Ok          |
| Warning  | Warning     |
| Ok       | Ok          |
+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample input data and desired results.  You mention "mapping tables", but it is unclear what that refers to in your query.

Comment: Does that help out at all?

Comment: You don't give sample data:( But only desired output. No. it doesn't help at all. Also please give them as code, not just text.

Comment: And BTW doing multiple joins is the right way, no?

Comment: The sample data is very similar to the lookup table, just a column with MCode and LCode called market and language. Multiple joins will show both as "ok" but does not take into consideration the other column for example GER language isnt in Switzerland but if we did multiple joins, it will validate them both as "ok"

Comment: Looking your code closer, stumped how that thing ever works for you without errors. Are you sure you supplied correct working code?

Comment: Please provide sample data, saying "similar" does not help at all.

Comment: I have updated the question :)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could instead do this with exist query, instead of joins. ie:

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN exists (select * 
from [dbo].[Lookup_Market] m 
where c.[campaignNameMarket] = C_Market.MCode and 
LEN(m.MCode) > 0
) THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning' End as C_Market,

CASE WHEN exists (select * 
from [dbo].[dbo].[Lookup_Language] l 
where c.[campaignNameLanguage] =m.LCode and 
LEN(m.LCode) > 0
) THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning' End as C_Language
FROM [dbo].[CTable] c;
```

EDIT:
As I said before, your samples are not covering all cases and not very helpful. However, at least now a little better than before. If that is exactly what you want:

```
SELECT 
--     c.campaignNameMarket,
--     c.campaignNameLanguage,
       CASE
           WHEN EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM dbo.LookupMap_MarketLanguage ml
                    WHERE c.campaignNameMarket = ml.MCode
                ) THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning'
       END AS C_Market,
       CASE
           WHEN EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM dbo.LookupMap_MarketLanguage ml
                    WHERE c.campaignNameMarket = ml.MCode
                          AND c.campaignNameLanguage = ml.LCode
                ) THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Warning'
       END AS C_Language
FROM [dbo].[CTable] c;
```

You can see [DBFiddle demo here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cb8dc95f983f2183f8f7bd79f87165f)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately this returns the same as using multiple joins.

Comment: @MustieMustafa, still not clear what you want. Anyway edited for that sample.